# AS3 Base class is final error when I didn't set it that way

Tags: actionscript-3, air, base-class

I'm getting the "Base class is final" error on a project that uses the AIR for iOS player. Problem is I didn't set the base class to be final. Also this only happens when I use AIR as the player.

Main - document class

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import parentfolder.*;
    import parentfolder.childfolder.*;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main () {
            addChild (new SplashScreen ());
        }
    }
}
```

Screen - inside parentfolder which is in the same folder as the document class

```
package parentfolder {
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Screen extends Sprite {
        public function Screen () {

        }
    }
}
```

SplashScreen - inside parentfolder

```
package parentfolder.childfolder {
    import flash.display.*;
    import parentfolder.*;

    public class SplashScreen extends Screen {

    }
}
```

So...there's no "final" anywhere in the code and the problem is isolated in the AIR player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class in AIR called Screen, which is declared as final.  You've used the `.*`notation on your imports, therefore `flash.display.Screen` is assumed as the base class for `SplashScreen`, instead of your custom `parentfolder.Screen`.

Since this class exists only in AIR, the problem does not occur in other players.

You should always use fully qualified imports (one for each class) to avoid naming conflicts like this.

Comment: Oh, guess I'll just change it to BaseScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html).

You are trying to extend from it in this line

```
public class SplashScreen extends Screen
```

Screen is declared as `public final class Screen`.

So you cannot inherit from a class that is [final](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#final).

Quoting the Adobe Docs,

> Specifies that a method cannot be overridden or that a class cannot be
>   extended. An attempt to override a method, or extend a class, marked
>   as final results in an error.